# Rails 4 API with Strong Parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a simple API with Rails 4, but with my "create" method, it all goes horribly wrong.

Here is the relevant part of my routes file:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
         # /api/... Api::
        scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
        resources :users
    end
end
```

**Here is the api/v1/users_controller.rb:**

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController

        protect_from_forgery except: :create
        respond_to :json

        def index
            respond_to do |format|
                format.html {render text: "Your data was sucessfully loaded. Thanks"}
                format.json { render text: User.last.to_json }
            end
        end

        def show
            respond_with User.find(params[:id])
        end

        def create
            respond_with User.create(user_params)
        end

        def update
            respond_with User.update(params[:id], params[:users])
        end

        def destroy
            respond_with User.destroy(params[:id])
        end

        private

            def user_params
              params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age, :location, :genre_ids         => [], :instrument_ids => [])
            end
    end
```

Whenever I try to add an API with JSON, I get "{"errors":{"name":["can't be blank"]}}"

It works to create a user with my regular controller, but I have a feeling my API controller is getting messed up because of the Strong Parameters.

Any suggestions for how to do this correctly in Rails 4?
Also, I have a few Has-Many-Through relationships through my user model. The API's user controller should be able to see that off the bat, right?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I'm now getting this error:
[image]

**EDIT:**

```
{
  "name": "Sally",
  "age": "23",
  "location": "Blue York",
  "genre_ids": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

**EDIT AGAIN**

Even with adding the User parameter in my JSON call, it still gives me the same error of the :user param missing. Am I using strong parameters incorrectly? In my "regular" users_controller, I can create a user easily with a form that I have set up, but with this API controller, I can't seem to create one with JSON. Any other suggestions?

**EDIT YET AGAIN**
**Here Is The Log From Start to Error**

```
rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-12-19 14:03:01] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-12-19 14:03:01] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-02-22) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
[2013-12-19 14:03:01] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=53778 port=3000


 Started GET "/api/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-19 14:03:02 -0500
 ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM  "schema_migrations"
 Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#index as JSON
 User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 Rendered text template (0.0ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 142ms (Views: 27.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
 [2013-12-19 14:03:03] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set   content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
 [2013-12-19 14:03:03] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set  content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


 Started POST "/api/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-19 14:03:37 -0500
 Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#create as JSON
 Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms

 ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: user):
 app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:40:in `user_params'
 app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:20:in `create'


 Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-  4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.7ms)
 Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
 Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.8ms)
 Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-  4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout   (31.6ms)
```

**EDIT #6**
Here is my "real" users_controller that lives in my app and not my API. The form creates a user from this controller and NOT the API controller.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @genres = Genre.all
    @instruments = Instrument.all

    render json: @users
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age, :location, :genre_ids => [], :instrument_ids => [])
    end
end
```

**ALSO - The User Form**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>

        <%= f.label :age %>
        <%= f.text_field :age %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>

        <%= f.label :location %>
        <%= f.text_field :location %>

        <br>

        <% Genre.all.each do |genre| %>
            <%= check_box_tag "user[genre_ids][]", genre.id %>
            <%= genre.name %><br>
        <% end %>

        <br>

        <% Instrument.all.each do |instrument| %>
            <%= check_box_tag "user[instrument_ids][]", instrument.id %>
            <%= instrument.name %><br>
        <% end %>

        <%= f.submit "Create My Account!" %>
    <% end %>
   </div>
  </div>

 <%= users_path %>
```

**Here is my user.rb File**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
has_many :generalizations
has_many :genres, through: :generalizations

has_many :instrumentations
has_many :instruments, through: :instrumentations

end
```

**Here is what I have in my routes file:**

```
namespace :api do
   namespace :v1 do
      resources :users
   end
end
```

**My POST Request**

POST /api/v1/users HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ "user": { "name": "Sally", "age": "23", "location": "Blue York", "genre_ids": [1, 2, 3] } }

**UPDATE**

I changed my strong-params to be this:

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age, :location, :genre_ids => [],   :instrument_ids => []) if params[:user]
end
```

So the "if" statement at the end makes the error go away, but whenever I post to my API, it gives me back "null". So this could be the same problem as before, but shown in a different way. But, at the same time, it could be progress!

**Here Is The Log For The Previous Update**

```
Started POST "/api/v1/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-21 11:38:03 -0500
Processing by API::V1::UsersController#create as */*
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

**FINAL UPDATE**
I was missing a few things, but the main thing that did it was that I was missing "Content-Type - application/json" as my Header.
I feel so accomplished! Thanks for all your help, everyone!

Comment: How are you making the call to your API?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I'll update in my OP for better formatting.

Comment: I guess specifically I'm using a Chrome extension called Postman that lets you make JSON or plain text calls. I'm making a POST call to http://localhost:3000/api/users

Comment: You need to mimic exactly how your form posts the `user` parameter hash.  I think you are missing the parent object `user` in your parameter which is why the `param not found: user` error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but getting the same error. I feel like I'm on the right track though!

Comment: could you add an log output from Started ... till Completed?

Comment: Sure @wkaha -- I added my log output from started to error in the OP. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @eightonrose where and how do you port data to your api? the posted structure should be like in answer 1. you may can show the code or the form you use for the post?

Comment: @wkaha - Yep! I added the code for my original controller, the form that is being used to create the user, and the model.

Comment: @eightonrose i've setup and all works fine. you may publish your routes? my was `resources :users`.

Comment: Hey @wkaha - That gives me hope! I must be close then! It's probably something really dumb that I'm missing. I added what I have in my routes.

Comment: I even created a new application and copied over the important parts-- and I'm still getting the exact same error there too.

Comment: @wkaha - I got it working! I think I was just missing a content-header in my post. Stupid me :( Thank you so much for you help!!

Comment: ++ for being so thorough!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your code parameters in the JSON you are posting should be inside `params[:user]`. So the JSON should look like:

```
{
  "user": {
    "name": "Sally",
    "age": "23",
    "location": "Blue York",
    "genre_ids": [1, 2, 3]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, great suggestion, thanks, but I'm still getting the same error. :( Any other suggestions?

Comment: I copied and pasted exactly what you had and restarted my server. Is there any chance it's just not seeing what's in my model for some reason?

Answer (score 4):

Rails 4 is a great choice for building APIs. I would go with the [rails-api gem](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api). It will perform way better than a full blown Rails stack.

I have built plenty of API's in Rails using the  Rails API gem. Usually in combination with RABL (which you can use to create nice templates to render your JSON). I am not a big fan of integrating an API directly into your production Rails app (serving websites and JSON) as you will create a big mess over time when starting to add more versions to your API. There are some very good Railscasts (www.railscasts.com): Search for API.

When accessing your API you would use a global filter in your application_controller.rb file. You could do something like this:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user, :except => 'users#index'

 private

 def authenticate_user
   @current_user = User.find_by_api_key(params[:token])
   unless @current_user
     render :status=>403, :json=>{:message=>"Invalid token"}
   end
 end

  def current_user
    @current_user
  end
end
```

In this case you would send the token in your request (that's quick and dirty, rather use the header instead) as a request parameter. You need to add the API key or whatever you want to use to your user model. Just create a migration adding api_key or however you want to call it to the user model or create a new table with keys, secrets etc. and a user_id field for your belongs_to (and a User has_many api_keys, or has_one). This way you can allow your users at any time to change their keys etc. (re-generate) without messing with usernames/password or even allow them to have multiple API keys with some tags (testing, production, etc). For your user signup you could add to your model:

```
before_create :generate_api_key
```

and then create a simple method like:

```
def generate_api_key
  begin
    self.api_key = SecureRandom.hex
  end while self.class.exists?(api_key: api_key)
end
```

Hope it helps!